# DBConcurrencyException при попытке обновлении БД

Tags: c#, ado.net

Пытаюсь обновить и добавить строки в таблице через `TableAdapter`, но выдает `DBConcurrencyException` "Нарушение параллелизма: UpdateCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей.".Все обновляется в одном потоке и на локальной БД, так что причин для конфликта параллелизма не вижу. В чем моя ошибка?

```
//Заполняю таблицу Categories в Dataset
GetCategories();
foreach (NorthwindDataSet.CategoriesRow c in northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.CategoryName + " : " + c.Description);
}
NorthwindDataSet.CategoriesRow row = northwindDataSet.Categories.NewCategoriesRow();
row.CategoryID = 12;
row.CategoryName = "One";
row.Description = "Two";
northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows.Add(row);
northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows[1]["CategoryName"] = "Three";
northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows[2]["Description"] = "Four";         
CategoriesTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(northwindDataSet.Categories);      
foreach (NorthwindDataSet.CategoriesRow c in northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.CategoryName + " : " + c.Description);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: А сколько в категориях записей перед тем, как вы добавляете новую? Не попадает ли свежедобавленная запись под изменение в этих строках? `northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows[1]["CategoryName"] = "Three"; northwindDataSet.Categories.Rows[2]["Description"] = "Four";`

Comment: @andreycha записей всего 8, а новая идет с ID=12. Так что я её не мог нечаяно отредактировать.